# Unable to read post data in java spark

Tags: java, freemarker

while posting data on server using `request.body()` gives me following string

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryq4DMNKuOxDn756Pn 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="checksum" 
test 
------WebKitFormBoundaryq4DMNKuOxDn756Pn 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="check_sum" 
testing
------WebKitFormBoundaryq4DMNKuOxDn756Pn--
```

but when I try to use `request.attribute()` to access post data it is giving me null value.

Comment: i tried request.queryParams("paramname") too but that also not worked

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the code you use to post and retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this for normal data :-

```
 request.getParameter("checksum");
  request.getParameter("check_sum");
```

And if it is  file or something use below :-

```
  Iterator<String> itr =  request.getFileNames(); 
  MultipartFile mpf = request.getFile(itr.next());
```

Comment: this is not HttpServletRequest object

Comment: & even if i convert it into HttpServletRequest object it also display null value

Comment: share your code in question, so people will know what object you have.

Comment: public class Data {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
post("/books", (request, response) -> {        
String line = (String) request.attribute("checksum"); // i want to read data which is send via POST.
}
}
return line;
       });

Comment: i got the missing part but not solution.. the thing is i was sending data using multipart somehow x-www-urlencoded works for me.